# imagemagick: center and resize multiple images an keep original filename

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Good morning,

I'd like to center and resize multiple images in a folder with different aspect ratios and keep the filename. The following is nearly what I like to have (it works perfect for the particular picture), but there I have to name every specific pic.

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:black -gravity center originalpic.jpg -thumbnail 300x300 -composite newpic.jpg
```

I tried to work with * to keep the original file name and to process every file in the folder but without success. Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify) command to work with multiple files.

```
mogrify -size 100x100 xc:black -gravity center -thumbnail 300x300 -composite *.jpg
```

Another way would be to iterate over the images in bash and use the same name as output to overwrite:

```
for f in *.jpg
do convert -size 100x100 xc:black -gravity center $f -thumbnail 300x300 -composite $f
done
```

Comment: That didn't work for me - there seems to be no changes at the images.

Comment: That's strange, it's what `mogrify` should do. If you are on linux you can iterate over the files in bash and use `convert` on them. Check the answer.

Comment: Second suggestion with bash doesn't work for me, too - I think because of "originalpic.jpg" (which of course I replaced with the original file name). I tried with *.jpg and $f, too, without success...

Comment: Second one over bash work's for me now. Thank you very much enrico.bacis!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it for me in general:

First size down to the height you want, e.g. to 364px:

```
mogrify -resize x364 *.jpg
```

And then, e.g. you want to get a dimension of 546x364px, this:

```
mogrify -extent 546x364 -gravity center *.jpg
```

But at image with original size of 512x768 background is getting filled with white color, so I tried

```
mogrify -extent 546x364 -gravity center -background black *.jpg
```

and

```
mogrify -extent 546x364 -gravity center -fill black *.jpg
```

but background is still white :-(

Comment: "mogrify" doesn't normally require "sudo".  I guess your *.jpg are in a directory where you don't have permission to write files or you don't have write permission on the *.jpg files themselves.